# Object Initializer with expression

Tags: c#

Is it possible to inilialize an object like this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Student
    {
        public bool IsStudent { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*
            ************Concise but not complied***********
            var student = GetDefault()
            {
                Age = 18,
                Name = "Nick"
            };
            */

            var student = GetDefault();
            student.Age = 18;
            student.Name = "Nick";


            Student GetDefault()
            {
                var stu = new Student()
                {
                    IsStudent = true
                };

                return stu;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think the repeated "student." is redundant.

What I want to talking about is a possiable C# syntactic sugar,not object initialize solution.The properties of Student may be a lot.

If it's not possible,it's apreciate to tell the possible design reason.

Comment: "I think the repeated "stu." is redundant" Nope, it´s not. This is the way you set properties on an instance. If you don´t like the language-syntax, chose another language or create your own one. Anyway your `GetDefault` should **return** something, in your case probably the `stu`-object.

Comment: No you can't. You would have to do that on the object constructor which you're not doing as in your image you're calling `GetDefault()` which just creates a new `Student` object and returns that. So in this case `stu` is not redundant. Polimorphism is a good thing however... you could create an overloaded method that accepts those values in the constructor for your ease.

Comment: Modify your `GetDefault()` function and pass parameters (Age and Name) to it ? You'll be able to call it like `var student = GetDefault(18, "Nick");`

Comment: Why don't you just add a constructor to your student class so you can do
var student = new Student(18, "name");

Comment: Default setters or class inheritance will solve this.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with HimBromBeere's statements. If you *really* want syntax close to what you described, you could do something like the following. That being said, obviously this now changes the meaning of the method and arguably this isn't really a great 'style' in my opinion... but it does achieve a syntax close to what you're asking for:

```
public class Student
{
    public bool IsStudent { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Student GetDefault(params Action<Student>[] modifiers)
    {
        var stu = new Student
        {
            IsStudent = true
        };

        if (modifiers != null)
        {
            foreach (var modifier in modifiers)
            {
                modifier(stu);
            }
        }

        return stu;
    }

    var student = GetDefault(
        s => s.Age = 18,
        s => s.Name = "Nick"
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should try something like this:

```
using System;

namespace Problem
{
    public class Student
    {
        public bool IsStudent { get; set; }
        public int? Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // GetDefault.
            Student Student_One = GetDefault();
            Console.WriteLine("IsStudent = {0} \nName = {1} \nAge = {2}", Student_One.IsStudent, Student_One.Age, Student_One.Name);

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");

            Student Student_Two = GetDefault();
            Student_Two.Age = 19;
            Student_Two.Name = "Nick";
            Console.WriteLine("IsStudent = {0} \nName = {1} \nAge = {2}", Student_Two.IsStudent, Student_Two.Age, Student_Two.Name);

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");

            Student Student_Three = new Student
            {
                IsStudent = true,
                Age = 20,
                Name = "Johnson"
            };
            Console.WriteLine("Name = {0} & Age = {1}" , Student_Three.Age,  Student_Three.Name);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        static Student GetDefault()
        {
            Student student = new Student
            {
                IsStudent = true
            };

            return student;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption - though comprehensible - is wrong. `student.` is **not** redundant.

Imagine someone would just call `GetDefault` **without** asigning its result to a variable - which is pure fine and valid.

```
GetDefault()
{
   ...
}
```

`GetDefault` returns an instance whose properties you modify afterwards. However as you don´t assign this object to any variable it will be garbage-collected soon. So when you *set* the properties it won´t have **any** efect at all, because there´s no code that may *read* it. In particular you can´t call `DoSomethingWithUpdatedValues` on that instance, because the instance is lost.

The syntax you want to avoid is the only valid syntax to achieve this. You could of course add parameters to your method, which however would change the methods **purpose**.

The cleanest solution in my opinion is to have a constructor that accepts the two parameters. There´s actually not much you can do on a `Student` that has no name or age at all, so just provide it to the constructor.